# Undefine globals in particular files

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am working on plugin system for my sails.js application. For security reasons I need to get rid of `sails` global variable, which holds data like config files' content, etc. I don't want to undefine it globally, since this would break my application.

Plugin's entry point would look like following:

```
module.exports = function (pluginManager) {
 return { ... }
}
```

Where `pluginManager` would be the only allowed reference to application's code.

Is it possible to execute plugin's code in sandbox-like isolated environment? I considered using `child_process` API, but I don't know how much it will affect performance and stability of the application.

Comment: Wow, sails uses global variables? What a terrible design choice!

Comment: Yeah, but from the other hand having to require every model would be quite a pain.

Answer (score 0):

In your globals.js i would set the Sails instance to false, just like:

> sails: true

Still, you could still access to globals via req._sails.